# Where should the «clear» button should be in a popover with multiple-choice drop-down list?

Tags: forms, gui-design, touch-screen

In a popover for a touch interface, I have to include a drop-down list where the user will  find more than 500 multiple choices to select from.

**What would be the ideal position (and microcopy) of a button to quickly deselect all checkboxes?**

My first instinct would be just beside the «apply/submit» button. What do you think?

[image]

Comment: Be wary too of how close the scrollbar down button is to the "Apply" button; users may inadvertently click Apply when trying to scroll down in this design. You should also consider putting the check marks on the left of the items (since it will make it much easier to read off which items have been selected).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Not next to the Apply button** for sure. Just a slight slide to the left and you clear your entire selection and have to redo it.

I would rather **place it next to the Close button**. Since even if they misclick, the punishment is not that severe - you cleared selection instead of closing list or you closed list instead of clearing selection (hoping it is not a long procedure to open the list again).

[image]